# I can't install anything

Tags: helpfile

When I run `sudo apt install lutris` then I get this error message

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
 lutris : Depends: python3-setproctitle but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: python3-distro but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: fluid-soundfont-gs but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: mesa-utils but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed or
                      lib32gcc-s1 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so as you might expect I ran sudo apt --fix-broken install and then I get this error message

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

what do I do?

Comment: Did you first run sudo apt-get update?  Then try the install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: I tried running sudo apt-get update and i got the error message-
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
        libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 is installed
         libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 1):

The current libc6 version is 2.31-4, I believe.  Maybe ubfan1 is right.  Try.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: I tried that but it gave me the same error message about needing to install 2.27-3ubuntu1.3
 how do i install this then? i know it is a specific package name but of what i do not know.